# css - wrapping text in menu

Tags: css

I've inherited this site and some of the css is messy.
Specifically, this new page

http://www.businesseventssydney.com.au/

has a blue horizantal menu bar. At first, some of the menu items had text that was very long and did not wrap in the menu. However, after some work and additional css, I managed to get the text to wrap, e.g. hover over "Why Sydney" then "Sydney Growing for the Future".

css as follows:

```
.second-level{
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    /*word-wrap: break-word;*/       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    /*word-break: break-all;*/
    white-space: normal;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
       -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

The menu text wraps great in FF and Chrome, i.e. words are not split up and entire words wrap to the next line. But, in IE, words are split before wrapping.

The weird thing is, there is the same version of this menu on another page, which works perfectly in all browsers and didn't need to do anything with it. See the following page:

http://www.businesseventssydney.com.au/about-us/

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a whole bunch of CSS, maybe you can just remove:

```
#topnav {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```